# dispatchEvent not showing pop-up

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As shown in the demo, `dispatchEvent` is not working as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V8uEN/

Key part:

```
btn.dispatchEvent(
    document.createEvent("MouseEvent")
    .initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false,
        0, null)
);
```

An alert should pop up after 1 second upon loaded, but it is not coming up and an error appears in the console:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.

I don't know where's the problem at since I found a [demo](http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljrinokx/dispatchEvent_2.htm) almost with the exact same code, and it is working but not mine.

Comment: worked for me.  using chrome here.

Comment: @TMcKeown - That's weird, I'm using Chrome 32 on Windows but it's not working.

Comment: sorry, it's not popping up automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
btn.dispatchEvent(
    document.createEvent("MouseEvent")
    .initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false,
        0, null)
);
```

Your problem is that `initMouseEvent` doesn't return anything.  You can't combine all of that into one line.  You need to break it up.

```
var mEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
mEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false,
    0, null);

btn.dispatchEvent(mEvent);
```

This is how it's done in the demo you linked to.

Comment: Ohh I didn't notice that was the problem... So used to jQuery and didn't realize it's not how it works in native JS.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
   alert("Clicked.");
});

setTimeout(function () {
  var mEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  mEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

  btn.dispatchEvent(mEvent);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, I realized I cannot chain them.